# How to loop and execute only one set files of files?

Tags: shell-script

I have a folder structure wherein I have a set of SQL statements starting with T and others with C. I would like to create a Shell script to loop through and execute all the SQL scripts that start with T.

Comment: Which database system?

Comment: dbeaver on Hive

Comment: Dbeaver does not feature a command line utility, so you should target your question to the dbeaver community.

Comment: Actually i'm trying to create a Shell script that executes the SQL scripts lying in a folder.

Comment: How do you do this with a single SQL script and dbeaver?

Comment: I have a list of SQL Scripts that perfoem some create and Insert functions in dBeaver. But, we have been manually trigerring them upto now. With a Shell script i would like to execute them based on Shell comands.

Comment: The keyword is *in dbeaver*. How do you do it from outside dbeaver? How do you start dbeaver so it runs a SQL script on a given database and exists?

Comment: Using the hive CLI may help you: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Cli Or beeline: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients#HiveServer2Clients-Beeline%E2%80%93NewCommandLineShell